# Plotting Graphics3D together with PlotLegends?

Tags: plotting, graphics

How do you use PlotLegends together with Graphics3D? The following code does not work.

```
  plot = Plot3D[{Sin[x y], Cos[x y]}, {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, RotationAction -> "Clip", 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
  Graphics3D[plot[[1]], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: PlotLegends is an option for plot functions that specifies what legends to use. it is not an option for Graphics3D as you can see by
Options[Graphics3D, "PlotLegends"]

Comment: @MartinRommel then how would you achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
plot = Plot3D[{Sin[x y], Cos[x y]}, {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
               RotationAction -> "Clip", PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}];

Legended[Graphics3D[plot[[1]], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All], 
 SwatchLegend[{Red, Green}, {"sin(xy)", "cos(xy)"}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is to use `Show` which automatically passes the graphics options into `Graphics(3D)`, e.g.

```
Show[plot, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

[image]

with `ViewPoint -> Front` added to improve the visual distinction with the original.